# How to print maven provided classpath

Tags: maven, maven-2, classpath, maven-3

I am here to get information on how to print maven `provided` class path. I am able to print maven `compile`, `test` and `runtime` classpath, but I can not find the refid for provided class path. Here is the resource I found useful for printing `compile`, `test` and `runtime` classpaths of maven.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts in the `provided` **scope** are by definition something that is *provided by the environment of your application* (web container etc.) - i.e. not something Maven is aware about after the build is done.

As you [can read here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies), however, you should be able to just use the `compile` and `test` **classpaths** for your purposes.